# Linear-gradient not applied entirely to background

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this issue where my linear gradient did not get applied all the way to the bottom. I have tried removing `style="background-image: url('img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');"` from div with id `design-me`. In the css file I used `background-image: url("img/bg-showcase-2.jpg"), linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, #fff 100%);` instead. I have tried other ways as well but will be too long to describe here. How do I approach this issue?

[Partially applied linear-gradient on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTK43.jpg)

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div id="design-me" class="col-lg-6 text-white showcase-img" style="background-image: url('img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 my-auto showcase-text">
       //.....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.showcase .showcase-img {
 background-size: cover;
 animation: fadeIn 1.5s;
}

.showcase-img::before {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 /* margin-bottom: -300px; */
 height: 400px;
 width: 100%;
 content: '';
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .showcase-img::before{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, #fff 100%);
 }
 @keyframes fadeIn {
     from {
       transform: translateX(100px);
       opacity: 0;
     }
     to {
       transform: translateX(0px);
       opacity: 1;
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `.showcase-img::before{`, I use `.showcase-img{` in the media query. I deleted `height: 400px;`. I have placed `max-height: 100%;` in the media query. So now, the image and the `linear-gradient` effect resize depending on the lenght of the list on the right.

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .showcase-img{
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0,
      #fff 100%
    ),url('../img/bg-showcase-2.jpg');
    max-height: 100%;
 }
 @keyframes fadeIn {
     from {
       transform: translateX(100px);
       opacity: 0;
     }
     to {
       transform: translateX(0px);
       opacity: 1;
     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that could occurs is the background not showing on the last pixels and creating a gap between 2 blocks. On this screenshot you can see how I managed to get this done after long minutes of testing by using :

- `padding-box` value on my `background-origin` variable.
- Be sure to use **0%** to **100%** values with the colors you set.

[image]